# Mathjax Function to print as laTex

Tags: javascript, drupal-modules, mathjax

I am using Mathjax module in my Drupal site. The text between `$ and $` is being rendered as laTex correctly. For ex:

`$ b^2 - b + 1 $` is rendered as:

[image]

But I also need to load and append some laTex Text with **JS/jQuery**. Here the text is **not rendered as laTex**. For example:

```
let divText = "<div>$ b^2 - b + 1 $</div>";

$(".div").html(divText);
```

Then the rendered output is:

[image]

Is there a **function** to which I can pass the text(divText) before putting it inside div so that it is rendered correctly?
If yes, what is that function ?

Comment: You can try what is said on this page: https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/advanced/typeset.html in other words, try issuing this command after the `div` insertion: `MathJax.typeset()`

Comment: Thank you so much. With your hint, I used MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub, "elementID"]); which solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using `MathJax.Hub.Queue()`. The final code is:

```
let divText = "<div>$ b^2 - b + 1 $</div>";

$("#divID").html(divText);

MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub, "divID"]);
```

**Note: I had to replace class with ID.